# Which types use a FileNameEditor in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, editor, propertygrid

I need to change the editor for a property attached to a .net PropertyGrid, but I cannot set the Editor attribute of that property, because the property was generated by a tool, including all attributes.

The desired editor is

```
System.Windows.Forms.Design.FileNameEditor
```

I can find many tutorials on the web to assign this editor to string properties by setting the editor attribute, but I cannot set the editor attribute in this case. However, I can advise the code generation tool to behave such that the string property which I want to be edited with the FileNameEditor becomes converted to another property with different type.

In order to do so, I would need to know which type is edited by the FileNameEditor as default. I didn't find any list on the web which would tell me for a given editor which types employ this editor automatically when displayed in a PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 0):

This editor works with strings only and is not attached automatically to any other type.

Answer (score 0):

According to Reflector, it's used only for 2 properties :

- `SqlConnectionStringBuilder.AttachDBFileName`
- `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.FileName`